# How can I handle mouse input and cursor in a WinAPI window?

Tags: c++, windows, mouse, winapi

Hello I'm studying game engine programming, but I got stuck with mouse input.

As for now I have only WinAPI window, which has a message pump and processing. For the mouse I used RAWINPUT, but there is a problem: I can't find any elegant way of handling the mouse cursor, for example making a menu in a shooter.

Raw input provides relative movement data directly from mouse driver, but how can I control the cursor with it? Or maybe I should make 2 message processing queues with filters on the mouse? I haven't found any real solutions in my searching yet.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use WM_MOUSEMOVE ?

Comment: @Exaila because I now do :)